# Adding backround color to certain part of text with MIGRADOC AND PDFSHARP

Tags: c#, pdf, pdfsharp, migradoc

I'm struggling to add background color on certain part of sentence(text), word with MIGRADOC and PDFSHARP. Any suggestions how to do ?

```
par.addText(coloredText);
```

This is how I tried to add text that should be colored but there is no way to setup for color, except for paragraph `(paragraph.shading.color = Color.red)`  but I need part of the text in the paragraph.

Thanks

Comment: Please add the code you have tried so far

Comment: @Vini.g.fer I add the code to the post .Thanks

Answer (score 3):

With `FormattedText` it is possible to determine the color of the text (unfortunately not the background) 
With the piece of code below it is possible to do this:

[image]

```
Paragraph par = section.AddParagraph();  
par.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;

// Use formatted text to specify the color
FormattedText ftext = new FormattedText();
ftext.AddText("Coloured Text");
ftext.Color = Colors.Red;

par.AddText("normal Text");
par.AddSpace(1);
par.Add(ftext);
par.AddSpace(1);
par.AddText("rest of the normal Text");
```